# Can't remove a snap package (unlinkat)

Tags: snap

When trying to remove android-studio with snap (sudo snap remove android-studio) I get the error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Remove data for snap "android-studio" (114) (unlinkat /home/kupperu/snap/android-studio/114/android-studio: read-only file system)

I've tried googling this but it seems like no one has asked me this before. Any help?